# What is the meaning of やるやない？

Tags: meaning, dialects, kansai-ben

> あなたも　なかなか　やるやないの〜

Um... is this supposed to be a form of `[positive verb] [negative verb]` chaining together? What does it mean?

Comment: なかなかやるやないの＞なかなかやるじゃないの. Is that what got you or is it what it means?

Comment: Not to be confused with the grammar pattern や否{いな}や

Comment: This is a prime example of what I call the "affirmative じゃない".  In this case, however, a dialectal やない is being used instead of the standard じゃない.

Comment: Thanks! So it's kind of like, "isn't it?"

Comment: If you are talkng to me, yes.  It is saying "You are doing (or 'have done') [Action X] pretty good, aren't (or 'haven't') you?"  Problem is quite a few J-learners seem to take it to mean the exact opposite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure due to lack of context, but there's a high likelihood that it's in **Kansai-ben/Kansai dialect**.

What's written is Kansai-ben negation. The Hyojungo/standard version would be

> あなたも　なかなか　やる**じゃない**の〜

Here are some links that should be helpful:

- [List of Hyojungo to Osaka-ben suffix conversions. Please refer to the 8th listing. (in Japanese)](http://hougen.u-biq.org/osaka.html)
- [Wikipedia Kansai-ben page for further reading. (in English)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansai_dialect)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes! This character spoke Kansai-ben I forgot to mention. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

> やるやないの

This is a Japanese dialect used mainly the Kansai region (Hyogo, Osaka, etc.).

Perhaps you have misunderstood which words are being used in the sentence:

> ≠ 「やる」 + 「やらない」
>   ≒ 「やるじゃない（の）」